# Using FileSystemWatcher to detect folder rename

Tags: c#, directory, filesystemwatcher

I have a file based application. FileSystemWatcher works fine for most of my uses apart from directory rename. here is an example of the code:

```
   class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var directoryWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher("D:\\Test")
        {
            NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.Attributes | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess |
                              NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Security | NotifyFilters.Size,
            Filter = "*.*"
        };
        directoryWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        directoryWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        directoryWatcher.Changed += FolderChanged;
        directoryWatcher.Created += FolderCreated;
        directoryWatcher.Deleted += FolderDeleted;
        directoryWatcher.Renamed += FolderRenamed;
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void FolderRenamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static void FolderDeleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static void FolderCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private static void FolderChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

inside d:\Test there is a folder. once I rename it nothing happens. I get no event whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: I am registered to all the 4 events. for the folder I never get a rename event only changed

Comment: This question is bit confusing, are you looking for the Rename event for the directory?

Comment: @un-lucky yes I am. I cant seem to get it.

Comment: You have unregistered the `FolderRenamed` event by using `-= FolderRenamed;` use `+=` for register those events

Comment: @un-lucky my mistake. copied wrong code...

Comment: @un-lucky  I changed the code to a simple console app that demonstrates the problem

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Quite a naive suggestion, but wouldn't the *.* filter exclude any files or folders which don't contain a `.`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is ok but you are missing notifiers

```
 watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
```

and also

```
// Add event handlers.
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
```

have a look at the full code example here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.renamed(v=vs.110).aspx